# To find the minimal polynomial $1+\sqrt 3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: proof-verification, minimal-polynomials

I have a rough idea about this question.
First, let $x=1+\sqrt3$, then I found that $x^2-2x-2=0$
Then, by applying Eisenstein test with the prime $2$, it is irreducible, hence, the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $x^2-2x-2$.
Is my answer right?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Check: How do you factor your polynomial?

Comment: This is trivial from the _definition_: The minimal polynomial is the monic polynomial _of  minimal degree_ that has $1+\sqrt 2$ as a root. So you just have to show there is no polynomial of degree $1$ - no need for Eisentein, no need to even mention the word irreducible.

Comment: If you have a root $a+b\sqrt{n}$ where $n$ does not have a rational square root, then $((x-a)+b\sqrt{n})((x-a)-b\sqrt{n})$ will be the minimal polynomial.

Comment: I think that the use of Eisenstein's is important because it shows that there is no degree $1$ polynomial that solves it. He would have to prove that $\sqrt{2} - 1$ is irrational... which is not necessary because the minimal polynomial is in fact the unique monic irreducible polynomial that has it as a root.

Looks good to me.

Comment: Your answer is wrong for an obvious reason: $x$ is a unit in the corresponding ring of integers, hence has norm plus or minus one. So the last term of its minimal polynomial has to be plus or minus one. See my answer below for a fast way to compute minimal polynomials of numbers like that one.

Comment: @user357980 RIght. I guess Pythagoras must have known Eisenstein's criterion...

Comment: Sorry guys, I just relise I up the wrong question, it should be find the minimal polynomial of 1+sqrt3, is the solution make sense now?

Answer (score 1):

(Edit: OP meant $1+\sqrt 3$, not $1+\sqrt 2$)

Yes, your solution seems correct! Since you also know that $1\pm\sqrt{3}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$ is a root of $x^2-2x-2$, and that a quadratic polynomial over a field has at most $2$ solutions you can see immediately that it is irreducible.

Comment: I just relise I up the wrong question, it should be find the minimal polynomial of 1+sqrt3, is the solution make sense now?

Comment: @user538443 Yes, it seems perfect!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: find the minimal polynomial $g(x)$ for $\sqrt{2}$ and then let $f(x)=g(x-1)$. Irreducibility is preserved by automorphisms, so $f$ is still irreducible. And $f$ is just $g$ shifted one unit to the right. So if $g$ had a root at $\sqrt{2}$, then $f$ has a at $1+\sqrt{2}$.

**Added**: your answer is wrong, and you don't even need to go through the computation to know it. The number $1+\sqrt{2}$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ (multiply it by minus its conjugate). Hence its norm is $\pm 1$. But its norm (modulo sign) is the independent term of the minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

If $x=1+\sqrt 2$ then $x^2 = 3+2\sqrt 2$, and so
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 3 & 2 \end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}1 \\ \sqrt 2 \end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{c}x \\ x^2 \end{array}\right]$$

The matrix on the left is non-sigular, so we can invert:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}1 \\ \sqrt 2 \end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{cc} -2 & 1 \\ 3 & -1 \end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c}x \\ x^2 \end{array}\right]$$

Hence $1=-2x+x^2$ and $\sqrt 2 = 3x-x^2$.

The minimal polynomial over $\mathbb Q$ would be $x^2-2x-1$.